# Pass mysql table data from php page to bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I have mysql table named **project** with columns named Project Name,
Project Number,Project Status,Project Start Date,Project End Date.
Also I have a php page called 'projects.php' where I am displaying the data from mysql table **project** in the page but I am showing only data from first 3 columns ( Project Name,Project Number,Project Status ).
Also for every row in php table I have given a link named **view** clicking which will trigger a modal.

I want to show data from all the columns of that particular row in the modal.
Please guide me how I can go forward with this situation.

I am very new to php, javascript, jquery. Hence unable to figure out how to pass the data to modal. Following is the code which might help.

Table in projects.php:

```
<table  class="table table-striped table-condensed">

<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>Project Name</th>
  <th>Project Number</th>
  <th>Project Status</th>
 </tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <?php 

        $sql = "SELECT proj_name, proj_status, proj_num, 
                FROM Project";
        $records = mysql_query($sql);

        while (  $proj =  mysql_fetch_assoc($records)   )
        {
            echo "<td>".$proj['proj_name']."&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#testmodal' data-toggle ='modal'>view</a></td>";
            echo "<td>".$proj['proj_num']."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$proj['proj_status']."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
   ?>
</tbody>

</table>
```

Following is my modal code: ( which is just basic one )

```
<div class="modal" id="testmodal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">

                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h3 class="modal-title"><b>Test Modal</b></h3>
                    </div><!--end of modal-header-->

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        This is my test Modal !!
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>

                </div>                  
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to stop using MySQL_* functions, they are officially depreciated. Instead you want to look at [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php)

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is store the results of your query into an array.

```
$projects = array();
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Project";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $projects[] = $row;
}
```

Then you can do a `foreach` loop on your table and modal.

```
<?php foreach ($projects as $project): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $project['proj_name'] ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='#testmodal' data-toggle ='modal'>view</a></td>
    <td><?= $proj['proj_num'] ?></td>
    <td><?= $proj['proj_status'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Doing in this way , I am not fetching any data from the database. Can you show me the code in a clear way how to fuse the while loop and for each code  for the tables. Please.

Comment: I have done the following: <?php 
                       while (  $row =  mysql_fetch_assoc($records) )
                       {
                        $projects[] = $row;
                       }
                       foreach ($projects as $project):
                  ?>
                         <tr>
                 <td><?= $project['proj_name'] ?></td>
                 <td><?= $proj['proj_num'] ?></td>
                 <td><?= $proj['proj_status'] ?></td>
             </tr>
              <?php endforeach; ?>

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you should:

1. Query all the fields you want in the SQL you provided.
2. Form table with all the fields but don't display cells you don't need in the grid. *style="display: none"* for *td*.
3. Show your modal with javascript and get the fields you want from the table row's cells.
4. In addition, you may name each table cell with a class, to get it easily with js.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly first update your mysql connection to mysql**i** further as a beginner you might want to try the plugin on github  to be found under:

https://github.com/nakupanda/bootstrap3-dialog

If you insist on the out of the box modal then at least try the example to be found here
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples